# Non destructive split() in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

You can make an array from a string and remove a certain character with split:

```
const str = "hello world"
const one = str.split(" ")
console.log(one) // ["hello", "world"]
```

But how can you split a string into an array without removing the character?

```
const str = "Hello."
["Hello", "."] // I need this output
```

Comment: `"Hello.".split(/\b/)`

Comment: Your two examples are markedly different. Is the delimiter meant to be a space, or a `.`?

Answer (score 0):

While you can use a capture group while splitting to keep the result in the final output:

```js
const str = "Hello.";
console.log(
  str.split(/(\.)/)
);
```

This results in an extra empty array item. You should probably use `.match` instead: either match `.`s, or match non-`.` characters:

```js
const match = str => str.match(/\.|[^.]+/g);

console.log(match('Hello.'));
console.log(match('Hello.World'));
console.log(match('Hello.World.'));
```

Comment: The first example ends up with an extra blank string in the array.